When do you need references and trait objects to have different lifetimes?
Rust allows references to have a different lifetime from the trait objects they reference.  For instance you can have a method like:
fn get<'a, 'b>(&'a self, key: &str) -> Option<&'a (dyn MyTrait + 'b)>;

However, in every case I can think of, it works just as well to say:
fn get<'a>(&'a self, key: &str) -> Option<&'a (dyn MyTrait)>;

So my question is simple:  Can someone provide a simple example to show the utility of a type like &'a (dyn MyTrait + 'b), where a single lifetime on the reference doesn't suffice?

The first signature doesn't really even make sense. The caller can specify any lifetime 'b since 'b is not bound to any parameter. Therefore, from inside the function you have to return something that satisfies dyn MyTrait + 'static. (Since 'b is unrestricted, it could be 'static.) The answer to your question is revealed in this problem: you use two different lifetimes when the lifetime 'a belongs to one input lifetime and the lifetime 'b belongs to a different input lifetime.

Note also that typically you can get by with one lifetime, because lifetimes of shared references (&) are covariant. However, lifetimes of exclusive references (&mut) are invariant, so in those cases you need two lifetimes. (&'a mut Foo<'a> is always wrong.)

@cdhowie The code definitely compiles, but you are saying it is useless, which is why I am confused?  The subtyping part of the reference https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/subtyping.html talks about dyn Trait<T> + 'a, but since trait objects can only be held by reference, I don't understand the utility of the + 'a.

It compiles but try to write an implementation that returns a &dyn MyTrait + 'a where 'a is anything but 'static. It won't work. Trait objects cannot only be held by reference. However, you need indirection even when you own them since they are !Sized. An owned trait object looks like Box<dyn Foo>, Arc<dyn Foo>, etc.

The utility of the 'a is when the value behind the trait object has a non-static reference. For example, if you have struct Foo<'a>(&'a str) and you impl<'a> MyTrait for Foo<'a> then you need to "surface" that captured lifetime when you convert the Foo to a trait object, to communicate to the rest of the system that it borrows something. The lifetime you use in that case is the same lifetime as whatever it happens to borrow from. If it doesn't borrow anything then you can use dyn MyTrait + 'static, or omit the lifetime specifier and let the compiler infer it from context.

In the second case it will infer Option<&'a (dyn MyTrait + 'a)> but in the case of e.g. Box<dyn MyTrait> it will infer Box<dyn MyTrait + 'static>.
